# Error "GraphViz's executables not found" when calling GraphViz layout from NetworkX in iPython notebook

Tags: python, graphviz, jupyter-notebook, networkx, enthought

I received the error "InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found, error GraphViz's executables not found" when trying to use the method graphviz_layout in my code.  The code works fine when graphviz_layout is replaced by spring_layout.  From the throwback exception information, it looks like it calls pydot_layout.  I have the pydot module installed through Canopy's package manager, but importing it does not help.  I have also pip installed graphviz and imported it with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

keywordTreeFile = open('decode_wordnet/keywordTreeFile.TXT','r') #keyword generation file
keywordTreeFileLineData = keywordTreeFile.readlines()

G = nx.Graph()
pairData = []

for i in range(0,len(keywordTreeFileLineData)):
    pairData = pairData + [keywordTreeFileLineData[i].split('\t')]
    pairData[i][1] = pairData[i][1].rstrip('\n')
    G.add_edge(pairData[i][0],pairData[i][1])

pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G)

nx.draw(G,
        pos=pos,
        width = 1.0,
        with_labels = True,
        font_size = 3,
        linewidths=.1
        )
plt.savefig("graph.pdf")
```

Here is the throwback exception information:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvocationException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e85a11cf6191> in <module>()
     15 
     16 #pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k=.15,iterations=50,scale=100)
---> 17 pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G)
     18 #labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos)
     19 nx.draw(G,

/Users/scott/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.pyc in graphviz_layout(G, prog, root, **kwds)
    245     This is a wrapper for pydot_layout.
    246     """
--> 247     return pydot_layout(G=G,prog=prog,root=root,**kwds)
    248 
    249 

/Users/scott/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.pyc in pydot_layout(G, prog, root, **kwds)
    269         P.set("root",make_str(root))
    270 
--> 271     D=P.create_dot(prog=prog)
    272 
    273     if D=="":  # no data returned

/Users/scott/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.pyc in <lambda>(f, prog)
   1800             self.__setattr__(
   1801                 'create_'+frmt,
-> 1802                 lambda f=frmt, prog=self.prog : self.create(format=f, prog=prog))
   1803             f = self.__dict__['create_'+frmt]
   1804             f.__doc__ = '''Refer to the docstring accompanying the 'create' method for more information.'''

/Users/scott/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.pyc in create(self, prog, format)
   1951             if self.progs is None:
   1952                 raise InvocationException(
-> 1953                     'GraphViz\'s executables not found' )
   1954 
   1955         if not self.progs.has_key(prog):

InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

System information:  I am using the lastest version and modules of Enthought Canopy on a 64-bit Mac with OS X 10.9.5.  Also, I am using an iPython notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing GraphViz on my Mac using macports:

```
sudo port install graphviz
```

Installing python packages is not enough in this case.  Nonetheless, this is a dependency that should have been taken of by Enthought.

Comment: I'm getting `Error: Port graphviz not found`

Comment: 4 years later, I'd suggest installing anaconda (or at least a conda env).  After doing so, it becomes a one liner to install both the Python package and the Mac app: `conda install -c anaconda graphviz python-graphviz`

Answer (score 0):

Often, you should start with a fresh installation of Macports

1. Remove old Macports

   sudo port -f uninstall installed
    
   sudo port clean --work --archive all
2. Import, install and compile recent Macports sources files

   cd ~
    
   curl -O https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.3.tar.bz2
    
   tar xf MacPorts-2.3.3.tar.bz2
    
   cd MacPorts-2.3.3/
    
   ./configure
    
   make
    
   sudo make install
    
   port version
3. (Optional) update Macports

   sudo port selfupdate
    
   sudo port upgrade outdated
4. Install Graphviz using your fresh Macports

   sudo port install graphviz
    
   sudo pip install --upgrade graphviz

Comment: port selfupdate worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu users:-

```
sudo apt-get install -y graphviz libgraphviz-dev
```

This installs the graphviz executables needed by python to display plots